# Databinding with a custom object to datagridview - Column Header Text

Tags: c#, data-binding, datagridview

I have an list of objects (PrintJob) that I bind to a DataGridView.  Here is a cut down version of the PrintJob object (Don't want to bore you completely!!):

```
public class PrintJob 
{
        private long pagesToPrint;
        public long PagesToPrint
        {
            get { return pagesToPrint; }
        }

        private long recipientRef;
        public long RecipientRef
        {
            get { return recipientRef; }
            set { recipientRef = value; }
        }
}
```

and I make a list of these objects and bind to the dataGridView like so:

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = uiModel.GetPrintJobs();
```

---

all good so far?

Everything displays fine expcept the Column Headers - which show the exact same as the Propery name in my object i.e. "PagesToPrint" appears in column header, where ideally, I would want it to display "Pages To Print" in the header text.

How do I get the Column Header text to show something a bit more readable - I guess based on the property name.

Cheers.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
 [DisplayName("Pages to print")]
 public long PagesToPrint {...}
```

etc (with `using System.ComponentModel;` at the top of the code file)

Comment: Can you also preset column widths and stuff like that with attributes?

Comment: No, you can't. You can control some things like the type-converter (used to render and parse the value), but that is about it.

Comment: (Sorry last question) Would I be able to bind to columns I have already set up using the designer?

Comment: I don't fully understand the question; but if the *designer* has already added the columns, no the [DisplayName] won't be used. If you use AutoGenerateColumns they will be (and I believe *new* designer uses will pick up the [DisplayName]). But it isn't hard to automate if you want a method you can run against a DataGridView to fix the column headers (let me know if you need this - I'd guess 10 lines).

Comment: Hi - sorry just come back from hols in Italy.  What I meant - is I have set up columns in an order and format I like using the VS Forms Designer. I just wondered if you could bind to these manually created columns - I'm guessing you would have to make use of the ColumnAdded event for the dataGridView and do some jiggery pokery - not sure whether all this negates the benefits of data binding in the first place ???  Cheers.

Comment: ahh, sorted it now by using the DataPropertyName property on each of the columns that binds it to your custom object.

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can use the designer with a bound data source. Just set the "DataPropertyName" property value of each column in the designer.

For example...for column 1 the "DataPropertyName" property value would be "PagesToPrint", whilst the "HeaderText" property would be the actual text ("Pages to Print"?) you want displayed as the column header.